# Checkbox checked is not working. HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, navbar, ischecked

I am creating the sliding navbar using the checkbox method.

*[But for only demo purpose i am changing the background to "blue"]*

**I used label and if checkbox is checked Its background changes to "blue". But It Is Not Working**

***Please Explain Why????***

[See the code
at  https://codepen.io/adi45code/pen/abmxgQj]

**HTML**

```
<div class="position-right">
        <div class="nav-ele home">Home</div>
        <div class="nav-ele about">About</div>
        <div class="nav-ele services">Service</div>
        <div class="nav-ele goals">Goals</div>
        <div class="nav-ele contactus">Contact Us</div>
      </div>
      
      <!--Checkbox Toogle-->
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <label for="checkbox"><span>ColorRed</span></label>
```

**CSS**

```
  .position-right {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #000000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    color: red;
  }
  #checkbox:checked +.position-right {
    background: blue;
  }
  
span,input{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding :10px;
}
input{
  top: 30px;
}
span:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ,,+,, selector only targets the next sibling of the element on the left side of the ,,+,, selector (in your case, your checkbox).

And because the `label` is the next sibling of your checkbox, your code wont work.

All you have to do is replace positions of your `div` and your `checkbox`, so that the `div` will come right after the checkbox (also, you have to put label before the checkbox, not after it).

Here is the fixed version, hope I helped you a little bit :)

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/vYXMoOY

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the position of the input checkbox, because ,+, selector only target the next sibling

```css
  .position-right {
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #000;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .2s;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    color: red;
  }
  #checkbox:checked + .position-right {
    background: blue;
  }
  
span,input{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding :10px;
}
input{
  top: 30px;
}
span:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" title="" type="" />
</head>

<body>
      <!--layout--> 
   <!--Checkbox Toogle-->
     <label for="checkbox"><span>ColorBlue</span></label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    
      <div class="position-right">
        <div class="nav-ele home">Home</div>
        <div class="nav-ele about">About</div>
        <div class="nav-ele services">Service</div>
        <div class="nav-ele goals">Goals</div>
        <div class="nav-ele contactus">Contact Us</div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```